# Mapping XML to Unrelated Objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I'm designing a process to get XML files from our client and load them to our database, creating an order on our side.

The snag is, and isn't there always one?, the client's XML really doesn't resemble the business objects we use to load data to our database.

So I have to design a way to get the format they specify into our custom objects.

I'm considering creating "on the fly" custom objects FROM their XML and then coming up with a "map" to translate their objects into ours.  That's where my head is at right now.

Essentially I don't want to write another data-load process that supports their data, I just want to get their data into our format.

I know this is basically a design question so I'm just throwing out my idea to see if it rings true with anyone else.  Or if someone has done this and has a suggestion, I'm very open to hearing it.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific programming language and environment in mind?  Also, what does your existing DB infrastructure look like?

Comment: You can use Linq-to-XML to convert their XML files directly into your objects.

Comment: I'm using C# with SQL 2005.  Right now we have an existing process, using our own business objects, that submits orders to our Great Plains database.  I'd like to just get their data into our format so I can hook into that process which I know already works.

Comment: XSLT? It really depends on the bigger picture of your IT architecture…

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the bigger picture of our IT architecture.  I'm just asking what most people are doing when they have to map an xml file to POCOs.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531565/linq-to-xml-to-poco-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tag, c# and xml, I would generate an event upon file reception (OS level) that triggers the small app you will have to make. Structure wise, I would go with CompanyName.Object1.

Read up on XDocument for parsing and what not. XElement and its Attributes.

Bottom line, it looks like a CRM kind of implementation and from my implementation experience, it's the longuest process: parsing of incoming data. You'll have to be thorough with your clients and have them write specific..

```
<Nodes name="SpecificName">
```

Nodes = LocalName

name = Attribute("name")

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a defined spec from the client so I should be able to rely on that to stay sane.  It's just a matter of getting their XML into our XML format.  I'm starting to lean toward XLST actually.  In the future, we may have other clients that will need to send their data in different formats, but we will always need to translate that data in our format.  That's starting to sound like XSLT to me.